# Amazon EC2 automated / scripted backup WINDOWS 2008 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, amazon-ec2

I was wondering if there was a way to backup a windows 2008 server instance from Amazon EC2 automatically (i.e. with no user intervention).

I have a recently setup server using EC2 and would like to setup a script to automatically backup the entire server incase something goes wrong.

I also would like to automate the backup of an RDS instance if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to answer my own question so far i have not really found a fully automated way of backing up instances from EC2, there are ways using the API to take snapshots however (looking at this currently).

with RDS there are programs out there (PremierSoft Navicat is one such example), that has the ability to script and automate backups of MYSQL databases so you can use this to backup the DB automatically.

you can also install mysql on the 2008 server accessing the RDS instance and use the MYSQL commandline tools to backup the DB that way if needed.

Kris

Comment: As long as you can dump everything to disk then buffer all future writes until the Snapshot is complete, the Snapshot service is enough. Looking into how to dump/buffer SQL and Windows. http://serverfault.com/questions/268742/lock-windows-disk-for-backup-ec2-snapshots

Comment: Also if you're interested I've put together a simple service that triggers hourly snapshots of Windows instances on EC2.

Comment: Hi Chris, with regards to the service you wrote i would be interested in trying it out to see if it suites what im trying to-do.

Comment: There's no message feature on here so you can email me and I can set you up with the code or whatever's easier for you - chris ... brass9.com

Comment: Hi, I'd be really interested in your script too, if it's publicly available? Thanks.