# AWS Windows SQL EC2/EBS application consistent snapshot

Tags: amazon-ec2, sql, amazon-ebs, snapshot, vss

Has anyone found a way to take a EBS snapshot for a Windows Server that maintains Application Consistency? In my case it's with SQL and I'd like to maintain SQL app consistency.

Either via quiescing the DB directly (as you can do on oracle
*alter database begin backup,
ec2-create-snapshot vol-abcd1234, 
alter database end backup*)
or via VSS as SQL is VSS aware?

Answer (score 0):

This question was [asked before](https://serverfault.com/questions/268742/lock-windows-disk-for-backup-ec2-snapshots), it has a couple of viable options.

You can always stop the server, start the snapshot, and then immediately restart the server. It's the safest option, but quite disruptive.

You could of course use SQL Server within RDS. In that case AWS takes care of backups for you, and I think if you take a snapshot in RDS it will take care of the details for you.

Answer (score 0):

[AutomatiCloud](http://www.automaticloud.net/) has an optional VSS-Agent that allows you to create consistent snapshots for applications providing an VSS snapshot-provider like MS-SQL or MS-Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

AWS now supports it via system manager.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/take-microsoft-vss-enabled-snapshots-using-amazon-ec2-systems-manager/